# MEF-Import into Dictionary

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mef

Iam currently refactoring a application and want to introduce MEF.
The Export class (class Apple) is finished and marked with Export-keyword...
On the import site I currently have a dictionary which is initialized as shown below:

```
Dictionary<int, Apple> dict = new Dictionary<int, Apple>();
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    dict.add(i, new Apple());
```

...

How can I initialize the dictionary using MEF?

Comment: Where would the `1` and the `2` come from? [Export metadata](https://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata)?

Comment: the add-method is now in a for loop

Comment: Okay you edited the question, but there is still a problem–how does your application now that it needs exactly 10 apples? How does it know that all those apples need to be of type `Apple` and not, say `GrannySmithApple`? Maybe what you really need is an `AppleFactory` (orchard?) that get's injected via MEF that knows these things.

Comment: can I do this: `Dictionary<int, IApple> dict = new Dictionary<int, IApple>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  doct.Add(i, container.GetExportedValue<IApple>());
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think your question boils down to, "How to I ensure that the container produces multiple instances of an object rather than reusing the same object every time it's requested." Well that's pretty easy–you just have to specify [`CreationPolicy.NonShared`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.creationpolicy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Consider this example implementation of `IApple`:

```
public interface IApple { }

[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
[Export(typeof(IApple))]
public class Apple : IApple 
{ 
    private static int appleCounter = 0;
    private int id;

    public Apple() 
    {
        this.id = ++appleCounter;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Apple #" + this.id.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here's one way that you might use it:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var catalog = new ApplicationCatalog();
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        IDictionary<int, IApple> dict = new Dictionary<int, IApple>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dict.Add(i, container.GetExportedValue<IApple>());
        }

        foreach (var pair in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

The key line of code here is `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]`. Without this, the only one `Apple` would ever be created. Of course this isn't quite as useful as you're probably hoping for. Here's another way to generate a dictionary that's a bit more flexible:

```
public interface IBasket
{
    IDictionary<int, IApple> GetAppleDictionary();
}

[Export(typeof(IBasket))]
public class Basket : IBasket
{
    private IDictionary<int, IApple> dict;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Basket([Import] CompositionContainer container)
    {
        this.dict = new Dictionary<int, IApple>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            this.dict.Add(i, container.GetExportedValue<IApple>());
        }
    }

    public IDictionary<int, IApple> GetAppleDictionary()
    {
        return dict;
    }
}

class Program
{
    [Import(typeof(IBasket))]
    private IBasket basket = null;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = new Program();
        program.Run();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        var catalog = new ApplicationCatalog();
        var container = CreateCompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
        foreach (var pair in this.basket.GetAppleDictionary())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }

    private static CompositionContainer CreateCompositionContainer(ComposablePartCatalog catalog)
    {
        var wrappedCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(catalog, new TypeCatalog(typeof (CompositionContainer)));
        var container = new CompositionContainer(wrappedCatalog);
        container.ComposeExportedValue(container);

        return container;
    }
}
```

The tricky part here is `CreateCompositionContainer`. This method ensures that the the `CompositionContainer` itself can be used to satisfy an import on an object it's composing. This allows the `Basket` to directly manipulate the container to generate all the apples it needs.

And just for the purpose of demonstration, here's one way you could also use the `[ImportMany]` attribute to accomplish something similar (although all those `[Export]`'s really make me cringe):

```
public interface IApple { }

[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
[Export(typeof(IApple))]
[Export(typeof(IApple))]
/* ..repeat N times.. */
[Export(typeof(IApple))]
public class Apple : IApple 
{ 
    private static int appleCounter = 0;
    private int id;

    public Apple() 
    {
        this.id = ++appleCounter;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Apple #" + this.id.ToString();
    }
}

class Program
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(IApple))]
    private IEnumerable<IApple> apples = null;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = new Program();
        program.Run();
    }

    void Run()
    {
        var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(this.GetType().Assembly);
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
        apples.Dump();
    }
}
```